# Como fazer com que o TimePickerDialog inicie com a hora atual?

Tags: android

Fiz um `TimePickerDialog`, porém não consigo fazer ele chamar de inicio a hora atual, sempre chama 00h00. Gostaria de saber onde estou errando.

Código:

```
private void chamarTimePickerDialog() {
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener  mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hora, int minuto) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), hora+ ":" + minuto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            capHora.setText(hora+ ":" +minuto);


            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            calNow.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calNow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
            calNow.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);

        }
    };
    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), mTimeSetListener,0, 0, true);

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Lari, alterei o titulo da sua pergunta para ficar mais fácil dela se encontrada. Aproveite e faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) também para aprender mais sobre o site.

Comment: obrigado gato! rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode indicar a hora e minuto inicial na altura da construção do objecto [TimePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html).

Veja a declaração do [construtor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#TimePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)):

```
TimePickerDialog (Context context, 
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener, 
                int hourOfDay, 
                int minute, 
                boolean is24HourView)
```

`hourOfDay` e `minute` são a hora e os minutos com os quais o *TimePickerDialog* é inicializado.

Você está a passar zero a cada um desses parâmetros,

```
TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), mTimeSetListener,0, 0, true);
```

daí ser inicializado com `00h00`

Altere o código para que fique assim:

```
private void chamarTimePickerDialog() {
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener  mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hora, int minuto) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), hora+ ":" + minuto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            capHora.setText(hora+ ":" +minuto);


            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            //Não é necessário, getInstance já retorna o calendário com a data e hora actual
            //calNow.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calNow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
            calNow.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);

        }
    };

    //Cria um calendário com a data e hora actual
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                                                   mTimeSetListener, 
                                                   Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
                                                   Calendar.MINUTE,
                                                   true);

    dialog.show();
}
```